# ARIMA component with seasonality - Using R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to use auto.arima function in R on my time series data.I used both with the original series and with log transformed series and below are the outputs:

With original timeseries:

```
> auto.arima(inflowts)
Series: inflowts 
ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,1,0)[12]                    

Coefficients:
          ar1
      -0.6812
s.e.   0.1431

sigma^2 estimated as 16565:  log likelihood=-137.88
AIC=279.77   AICc=280.4   BIC=281.95
```

With log transformed series this is what I got:

```
> auto.arima(inflowts1)
Series: inflowts1 
ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,1,0)[12]                    

Coefficients:
          ar1
      -0.6695
s.e.   0.1488

sigma^2 estimated as 0.008878:  log likelihood=20.97
AIC=-37.93   AICc=-37.3   BIC=-35.75
```

The difference is only AIC and BIC parameters have become better when the transformed variable is used.

Since this data has seasonality my question is how to handle the seasonal component from here as it is giving both p and q values as 0 [ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,1,0)[12]   ]

Any pointer on how to handle such scenario will be highly appreciated.